# How can I compile and run this OpenCV C++ code in Windows 10?

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation, makefile, mingw

I'm trying to get this sample project going on my Windows 10 laptop:

Vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZNYoL8rzPY
Code: http://cvlab.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/cvlab2/files/software/brief/BRIEF_demo-0.5.zip

I have OpenCV 3 for Windows, and I'm trying to use MinGW and a modified Makefile to get it going:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -DHAVE_INLINE -msse4.2 -O3

SRCS = main.cpp BRIEF.cpp
PROG = BRIEF

OPENCV = -I"C/opencv_3/build/include" -L"C/opencv_3/build/x64/vc12/lib" -lopencv_core243 -lopencv_highgui243

$(PROG) : $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(PROG) $(SRCS) $(OPENCV)
```

When I run "make" (via MinGW), I get the following:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe
g++ -g -Wall -DHAVE_INLINE -msse4.2 -O3 -o BRIEF main.cpp BRIEF.cpp -I"C/opencv_3/build/include" -L"C/opencv_3/build/x64/vc12/lib" -lopencv_core243 -lopencv_highgui243
In file included from main.cpp:26:0:
BRIEF.h:31:23: fatal error: opencv/cv.h: No such file or directory
 #include <opencv/cv.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from BRIEF.cpp:26:0:
BRIEF.h:31:23: fatal error: opencv/cv.h: No such file or directory
 #include <opencv/cv.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'BRIEF' failed
mingw32-make: *** [BRIEF] Error 1
```

This is what I have tried. I am open to pretty much any solution that lets me run OpenCV C++ on Windows, particularly this project. I don't mind downloading other/older versions of OpenCV for example.

### Edit

Folder structure:

```
 Directory of C:\opencv_3\build\include

06/08/2016  01:45 PM    <DIR>          .
06/08/2016  01:45 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/08/2016  01:45 PM    <DIR>          opencv
06/08/2016  01:45 PM    <DIR>          opencv2
```

Comment: What is the basic folder structure of your project? Can you perform a `dir "C\opencv_3\build\include"` from the directory you're running `make` from and see a `opencv` directory?

Comment: You should probably avoid to use version 2.4.3 (it's outdated). Now version 3.1 is available

Comment: @Kupiakos I have edited my question, feel free to ask more I'll provide all the info I can.
Miki I don't think I have version 2.4.3, is there a quick way to check though? And yeah I don't mind downloading a different one if that's how I can make this work.

Comment: silly question but. Is there a cv.h inside the opencv directory? the compiler is not seen it.